# Performance based difference between nil and empty string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to clear the value of `UITextField` after assigning. I can done it with `nil` or empty string `""`. There are 500 `UITextField` in one app like this way.

Performance & Memory based which one is good?

**Reference Code:**

```
let a = ""
let b:String? = nil
print(a.isEmpty) //true
print(b?.isEmpty  ?? "value is nil") /*Value is nil*/
```

**Note:**
There are 500 implicitly unwrapped variable also. I know it was poor when implicitly unwrapped `var`. But, I must use like that only.

Comment: make a extension file for textFeild and use that extension top clear the values whenever you want to will save memory. Should I show you a demo ?

Comment: @iOSGeek , yes bro you are correct. I know. But, I need to know performance based difference `""` and `nil`  Thank you.

Comment: I think `nil` is better than empty string what `nil` does is clear it object  from memory  however empty string still occupies  memory.

Comment: @MikeAlter , Yes bro you are correct. I need to sure about that. Thanks bro.

Comment: There’s a good chance that it’s not going to make a material difference one way or the other. But if it concerns you, benchmark the memory impact it in Instruments and benchmark the speed difference with performance unit test (with release build). I would have thought, for example, that 500 text fields (rather instantiating them as you need them, just in time) would have a greater impact than string vs `nil`. And if you have 500 text fields, isn’t it possible that they’ll eventually have values, making the memory impact of empty string vs `nil` even less relevant?

Comment: @Rob , Great tip. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I want to choose in between nil and `" "` . I will go for nil parameter as `nil` is better than sending a empty string as according to me string will be taken as a string even if its of one `char` length and `nil` is taken as empty which will actually save memory not a big difference. But, in case of 500 `UITextFields` yes it matters go for `nil`.

Comment: nice answer :) Thank you bro :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`nil (id)0` is used to represent a null pointer as an objective-c object.

`""` is an empty string constant or string whose length is 0.

```
if dictionary.value(forKey:"aString" ) == nil
```

Check if the specific key is present in a dictionary.

```
if dictionary.value(forKey:"aString")  == ""
```

This line checks if there's an entry in dictionary with "aString" key and compares that entry with empty string. The result will be one of the following:

- is false if there's no such entry for your key
- is true if there's entry for your key and that entry is empty string

In **Swift**, `nil` is not a pointer—it is the absence of a value of a certain type. Optionals of any type can be set to nil, not just object types.

**Optional String**

```
let myOptionalString: String? = nil
var myOptionalString: String? // myOptionalString is automatically set to nil
```

**NOTE** : If you define an optional variable without providing a default value, the variable is automatically set to nil for you:

**Non-Optional String** : Check for zero length.

```
let myString: String = ""

if myString.isEmpty {
    print("String is empty.")
    return // or break, continue, throw
}
```